# How to simplify return's statement from try-catch

Tags: c#, exception, code-duplication

How can I simplify the following code:

```
try
{
    var metadata = GetMetadata();
    return metadata ?? _provider.GetLatestMetadata(guid);
}
catch (AuthenticationException)
{
    return _provider.GetLatestMetadata(guid);
}
catch (HttpUnauthorizedRequestException)
{
    return _provider.GetLatestMetadata(guid);
}
catch (WebException)
{
    return _provider.GetLatestMetadata(guid);
}
catch (VcenterException)
{
    return _provider.GetLatestMetadata(guid);
}
```

I would like to avoid code duplication.

Is it possible?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Implement a re-try mechanism?

Comment: I don't see any purpose of exception catching here.

Comment: Why don't you catch universal base `catch (Exception)` if you want to avoid code duplication?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to do a catch-all and really need to avoid duplicate code, you can catch the specific exceptions with an exception filter:

```
try
{
    var metadata = GetMetadata();
    return metadata ?? _provider.GetLatestMetadata(guid);
}
catch (Exception ex) when ( ex is AuthenticationException
                            || ex is HttpUnauthorizedRequestException
                            || ex is WebException
                            || ex is VcenterException
                          )
{
    return _provider.GetLatestMetadata(guid);
}
```

Comment: Oh. `when`...So many years of programming and actually I just have learned this...Even never heard this before. Just wow.

Comment: It is just a C# 6 operator, so it is still new :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Looks like I was too happy seeing null-conditional operator, string interpolation and default values for auto-properties and didn't notice this. Thanks for explanation! :)

Comment: Without the C# 6 operator `when` do I need to `throw` exception inside `catch`?

Comment: You can rewrite this as a regular `if` of course. In your else branch, just `throw;`.

Comment: `if (ex is AuthenticationException || ..)
  {
           return ..
   }
  else { throw; }` 

like this? or I can throw without `else`?

Comment: You can do both. No problem.

Comment: I asked because I didn't any `throw` in my code question